# How to skip missing data in Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Let's say that I have html page something like this:

```
...
<a class="hehe"><span>joke23</span></a>
<a class="hrtojoke" href="link/to/joke23"></a>
<a class="hehe"><span>joke24</span></a>

<a class="hehe"><span>joke25</span></a>
<a class="hrtojoke" href="link/to/joke25"></a>
...
```

As You can see I don't have link to `joke24` ;)

I want to that to every joke assign his link. If link does not exist exist I want assign it as `None`.

**My code**:

```
...
def parse(self, response):
    for joke, link in response.css(itertools.zip_longest(response.css('a.hehe'), response.css('a.hrtojoke')):
        yield {
            'name_joke': joke.xpath('span/text()').extract_first(),
            'link_joke': link.css('::attr(href)').extract_first(),
        } 
...
```

As You can guess, this code works, but no correctly

**Current Output**:

```
...
{'name_joke': 'joke23', 'link_joke': 'link/to/joke23'}
{'name_joke': 'joke25', 'link_joke': 'link/to/joke25'}
error..
...
```

**Desired Output**:

```
{'name_joke': 'joke23', 'link_joke': 'link/to/joke23'}
{'name_joke': 'joke24', 'link_joke': None}
{'name_joke': 'joke25', 'link_joke': 'link/to/joke25'}
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for item in response.xpath('//*[@class="hehe"]'):
        joke = item.xpath('./span/text()').extract_first() 
        link = item.xpath('./following-sibling::*[1][@class="hrtojoke"]/@href').extract_first()
        yield {'name_joke': joke, 'link_joke': link}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'name_joke': 'joke23', 'link_joke': 'link/to/joke23'}
{'name_joke': 'joke24', 'link_joke': None}
{'name_joke': 'joke25', 'link_joke': 'link/to/joke25'}
```

Comment: It's an awesome solution. Your answer definitely deserves a checkmark @Konstantin. However, I've got a question on this portion `*[1]` defined within xpath in `line` variable. What does that mean actually? Provided +1. thanks.

Comment: It means that it get **any** first element follow to previous , you can also write `a[1]` to get only `a` elements

Answer (score 0):

Just use a  try-except to catch the exception.
*Remember to catch the exact exception.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for joke, link in response.css(itertools.zip_longest(response.css('a.hehe'), response.css('a.hrtojoke')):
        name_joke = joke.xpath('span/text()')extractfirst()
        try:
            link_joke = link.css('::attr(href)').extract_first()
        except:  # pls add the exact exception you want to catch.
            link_joke = None
        yield {
            'name_joke': name_joke,
            'link_joke': link_joke
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it's not the point. I will have None assign to joke25, but I have link to this joke. I don't have link to joke24. I edited my question